# How to assign REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN privelege to a user in azure database for mysql?

Tags: mysql, azure-mysql-database

I created two azure database for mysql servers to simulate the master-replica architecture.

On replica server, I ran the below command and got the error
Command:-

```sql
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='<server-name>.database.azure.com', MASTER_USER='<user_name>', MASTER_PASSWORD='<password>',MASTER_LOG_FILE='<file_name>', MASTER_LOG_POS=<position>
```

Error:-

```
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
```

so after that I tried running this command, then got the following error

```sql
 GRANT REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN ON *.* TO 'vanshmittal_official'@'%';
```

Error:-

```
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the GRANT OPTION privilege(s) for this operation
```

I have logged in as vanshmittal_official, here are the privelege I have

```sql
 show grants for 'vanshmittal_official'@'%';
```

[image]

[image]
Can anyone please help, provide suggestions of what wrong I am doing?
Also is it possible for me to get super privelege as a user?
Thanks!

Comment: Azure, like other cloud vendors, doesn't allow you to have that privilege directly. But they provide a procedure `mysql.az_replication_change_master()` so you can configure replication. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/how-to-data-in-replication